# issues with LSA-08 line sensor for line tracing

Tags: line-following

I am using LSA-08 self calibrating sensor for line following purpose. But the problem with my sensor is it can't distinguish between faint blue color and white color (having RGB values 185, 217, 235). Is there any technique for distinguishing them ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Need a solution soon